# Saving the ID of the button clicked in a integer variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several buttons on my side they all have ID's named "1" - "10". I have a function that is called when the buttons are clicked and I would like to make this function read the buttons ID and save it as a integer variable. this is what I have so far:

Edit: I updated my code with a suggestion from the answers. No success so far. It does not alert me the ID.

JS/JQUERY

```
var transform = function(obj){
   var id = obj.id;
   alert(id);    
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="JavaScript: transform(this)" id="b1">

<div class = "test" > </div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
 .test {
        position: absolute;
        width: 20%;
        height: 10%;
        background-color: black; 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a click event - `href` isn't the same as an `onclick` event. Ideally you'd add a common class to all these links, then make 1 simple handler:

```
<a class="link" id="1">
    <div class="h1">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/256" />
    </div>
</a>
```

And the jQuery

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
    console.log(+this.id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your method but it does not seem to work. Can you check why? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bgpJzK

Comment: @Alter - `var id = obj.id;` - `obj` isn't defined - it's `this.id` as the answer shows. Check the console - youll see the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just put

> this

in your HTML like this

```
<a onclick="transform(this)" href="http://www.google.com" id="1">
```

By doing this, you can get the js object of the clicked element and from it you can easily get the value of any used attribute.

```
var transform = function(obj){
        var id = obj.id;
        alert(parseInt(id));
}
```

[Chckout this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odpvwnv9/9/)

Comment: Thanks. I tried your method, but with no success. I will post my code now in the mainthread.

Comment: Let me make some changes in my answer. last time i was in  hurry